# Styling list item menu

Tags: html, css

I have a menu which works on hover.
The list of items is given below.
I want to style it in such a way that the image appears on the extreme left hand side and the text on the extreme right hand side.

HTML:

```
<td style="width:30px" class="tableIconHambMenuBlackBgOnly">
    <ul id="css3menu1">
        <li> 
             <a href="#" title="Hamburger Menu">
                 <span><img src="./images/hamburgMenu_16px_Black.png" width="16px" height="16px" alt=""></span>
             </a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="./images/img1.png" alt="">text1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="./images/img2.png" alt="">text2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="./images/img3.png" alt="">text3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="./images/img4.png" alt="">text4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</td>
```

I have tried inserting divs but the layout breaks.

CSS:

```css
ul#css3menu1,ul#css3menu1 ul{
 list-style:none;background-color:none;border-width:0px;border-style:transparent;display:inline-block;}
ul#css3menu1 ul{
 visibility:hidden;position:absolute;right:30px;top:0;opacity:0;-moz-transition:all 0.5s;-webkit-transition:opacity 0.5s;-o-transition:opacity 0.5s,visibility 0.5s;transition:opacity 0.5s;background-color:#transparent;border-radius:0px;-moz-border-radius:0px;-webkit-border-radius:0px;padding:4px 4px 0px;}
ul#css3menu1 li:hover>ul{
 visibility:visible;opacity:1; z-index:9999;}
ul#css3menu1 li{
 width:200px;position:relative;display:block;font-size:0;border-width:1px;}
ul#css3menu1 li:hover{
 }
ul#css3menu1 ul ul{
 position:absolute;right:100%;top:0;-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 0px #63dbc3;-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 0px #63dbc3;box-shadow:0px 0px 0px #63dbc3;}
ul#css3menu1{
 width:20px;font-size:0;position:absolute;display:block;float:left;border-radius:0px;-moz-border-radius:0px;-webkit-border-radius:0px;margin-top:6px;}
ul#css3menu1>li{
 width:30px;margin:-12px 0px 0px -30px;}
ul#css3menu1 a:active, ul#css3menu1 a:focus{
 outline-style:none;}
ul#css3menu1 a{
 display:block;vertical-align:middle;text-align:left;text-decoration:none;font:12px ROsans,Arial,sans-serif;color:#000000;cursor:pointer;padding:0px 2px;background-color:transparent;border-width:0px;border-style:transparent;}
ul#css3menu1 ul li{
 float:right; margin:-6px 2px 0px 1px;}
ul#css3menu1 ul a{
 text-align:left;padding:10px;background-color:#f6d4b2;border-radius:0px;-moz-border-radius:0px;-webkit-border-radius:0px;font:12px ROsans,Arial,sans-serif;color:#000000;text-decoration:none;border-style:solid;border-color:#fff;}
ul#css3menu1 li:hover>a,ul#css3menu1 li a.pressed{
 border-style:none;color:#000000;text-decoration:none;border-style:solid;border-color:#fff;}
ul#css3menu1 ul li img{
 border:none;vertical-align:middle;margin-right:20px;padding-left:5px;}
ul#css3menu1 span{
 display:block;overflow:visible;background-image:url("arrowsub.gif");background-position:right center;background-repeat:no-repeat;padding-right:0px;}
ul#css3menu1 ul span{
 background-image:url("arrowsub.gif");padding-right:0px;}
ul#css3menu1 ul li:hover>a,ul#css3menu1 ul li a.pressed{
 background-color:#fbead9;color:#000000;text-decoration:none;}
ul#css3menu1 li.topmenu>a{
 background-color:#f6d4b2;border-radius:0px;-moz-border-radius:0px;-webkit-border-radius:0px;}
ul#css3menu1 li.topmenu:hover>a,ul#css3menu1 li.topmenu a.pressed{
 background-color:#f6d4b2;}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you right, but have you tried to put text into span and then in the css set  to span float right and to the image float left (of course you need to clearfix the containing element) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a float to the image like a float:left and on the li you can put text align right..

```
ul#css3menu1 li { text-align:right}
ul#css3menu1 li img {float:left}
```

that way you can keep the html same

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a background image  since it's extremely unlikely that these images are content. Styling should be in the CSS.

```css
li {
  background-position: center left 4px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  line-height: 1.25rem;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
li.home {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-16-16-5.jpg);
}
li.contact {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-16-16-4.jpg);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="home">Home</li>
  <li class="contact">Contact</li>
</ul>
```

As a bonus, it makes the HTML much cleaner and allows for hover effects.